# PHP register form

Tags: php

I need a register form for

- first name
- last name
- email
- username
- passward.

I have done the first name check right?

```
$errors = "";

if(!isset($_POST['First Name']))
    $errors .= " Please provide a First Name.";

    echo "reg done";
}else{
    echo $errors. "enter your first name please";
```

Comment: Does it do what you want it to do? What if someone enters a space (" ") for their first name? I'd imagine `isset` should be replaced with `empty`, if nothing else.

Comment: ` )else(` syntax error, or? And plz write nice looking code. Use tab or spaces for blocks.

Comment: No it doesn't, is there another way to validate it?

Comment: you need to provide more detail, like the rest of the code. the code you have does not look correct either. If(condition){true}else{false}, for starters.

Answer (score 1):

This form only checks that the _POST variable exists, not whether it has any content (it will resolve as false regardless of whether they leave it blank or not. You're also not using curly brackets correctly (learn the difference between parenthesis and curly brackets). What you want is:

```
$errors = "";
if(!isset($_POST['First Name']) || trim($_POST['First Name'])==""){
    $errors .= " Please provide a First Name.";
    echo "reg done";
} else {
 echo $errors. "enter your first name please";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seriously, may i suggest reviewing the plain simple PHP Docs at

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php

I think you need more than just a little help on a boggus question, your syntax is lacking everything that makes a good script...

For instance you'd write the same code along the lines of

```
if(!isset($_POST['FirstName'])){
    $errors .= " Please provide a First Name.";
}

echo "reg done";

}else{  // <---------- you have an else here lying after some code and it doesn't seem to start anywhere...
    echo $errors. "not done";
}
```

Comment: I would like some help with registering my form as i'm a student, i am very new to php. Nothing seems to echo out when i test it. I would like a message echoed out stating fields need to be filled in or ok if all of them are filled in. The code that i have for php is